# Uploading app to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I'm trying to upload my app to the App Store with the application loader provided by Apple, but when I try to send my source code to Apple I get this error:

> "The application wrapper must end in .app
>   /var/folder/4h/2xtkks0x5nvgz75c87r_cjdm0000gn/T/BowledOver!.zip/BowledOver!
>   is invalid"

What do I need to add to my project so that it can send successfully?

Comment: How are you archiving your app?

Comment: Yeah, I was confused by "send my source code to Apple" comment. I have a distribution scheme in which I've signed my app, I build, I zip the new signed .app, and then I use "Application Loader" to send that to Apple. How exactly are you preparing the "source code" that you're sending to Apple?

Comment: By "Application Loader" to you mean the independent application "Application Loader" or the one built into Xcode?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: When I said Application Loader, I personally was referring to the separate application which is available from the "Xcode" menu under "Open Developer Tool submenu. That works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of Xcode, attempt to make the submission using the application loader build into Xcode.

[image]

[image]

After this click distribute, and follow then on screen guides.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an explanation of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When you make Ipa file manually, the name of destiny folder where you copy the contents of xcarchive file must be "Payload". Doing this this error message disapears.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the bang (!) in your filename is not allowed by the App Store. Your display name can differ from your binary name, so you can still use "Bowled Over!" vs "BowledOver".

Comment: The same error? Or a similar error without the "!" in the names?